# Update injected domain object in Java EE 7 CDI Application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, producer

This may be more of a conceptual than technical question however I hope you can provide me some advice on how to proceed.
We are developing a large Java EE 7 application that works stateless and is getting requests from clients. Each request contains a session ID and each session contains a large amount of domain objects that are session specific.
We created a RequestScoped class that contains all the producer methods for our domain objects. When a request comes in with a session ID we call a setter Method on the producer to set the session ID in the producer CDI bean. 
Now if one of the RequestScoped classes along the chain needs one of the domain objects it has an @Inject definition at the beginning of the class to get the domain object from the producer. The Producer itself has a connection to an inmemory DB to retrieve the domain objects from there and keep them in a local variable for future use in this request.

Now to the question: Say Bean A injects Domain Object X and changes some properties on X. Do I have to call an "update" Method in my producer and pass Domain Object X as a parameter or is it updated automatically in the context?
Upon injection in the Request Scope the CDI container creates a proxy to access the actual bean. Would this proxy be usable just like a regular reference? E.g. if I call a method on my injected bean, would it update the bean behind the proxy?

Comment: That sounds to me like "I don't really understand what a proxy is". What you are asking about here is exactly solved by the fact that CDI uses proxies; yes it just works. Are you asking perhaps because you already tried and something didn't pan out as you expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this will probably get me downvoted, but I'll answer anyway because I'm hoping it'll be valuable to you. It sounds like you guys have put the cart a mile in front of the horse.

> The Producer itself has a connection to an inmemory DB to retrieve the domain objects from there and keep them in a local variable for future use in this request.

You're trying to re-invent what's called replicated, distributed, sessions. Don't do this. Use @SessionScoped beans and keep the business logic in your app, and let your infrastructure handle the application state. Imagine yourself years from now looking at this application, when your boss wants a UI refresh and your customers are demanding new features. You're going to not only maintain the application, but an entire mess of a buggy distributed framework you built :(

Instead, you can use a distributed in-memory DB to hold your session state and cache it locally! Apache Tomcat/TomEE has great support for this (I'm not sure what application server you are using)

Take a look at:

- https://github.com/magro/memcached-session-manager (Use Couchbase, Redis, Memcached, Hazelcast, GridGrain, or Apache Geode)
- http://community.gemstone.com/display/gemfire/Setting+Up+GemFire+HTTP+Session+Management+for+Tomcat (Specific to Gemfire)

We use the first with great success. If the Tomcat instance encounters a session id it doesn't have locally, it pulls it from the data grid. When it's done processing the request, it publishes that session changes back to the data grid. This is extremely fast and scales beautifully.

If your application server does *not* have the ability to do this, instead of writing the application in the painful manner you are doing, I would concentrate your efforts on writing a session replicator like memcached-session-manager. Good luck!

Comment: We are using Hazelcast as in-memory DB across several servers and Oracle Weblogic 12.2.1.0.0 as application server. We are aware of session replication across the cluster but there is more to it than just keeping session context, e.g. configuration, tracking all requests for reporting, etc.